# Docker in VM Windows10

Tags: windows, docker, virtual-machine, virtual

I am New with insall and use Docker.

Is it possible to run Docker on a viertual machine with Windows 10?

I had treid and got Problem with WLS..

I have installed on my PC with Windows 10 but I need to use it on a VM.
Please i need help

Comment: There's definitely a time-honored tradition of running Docker in a Linux VM; the current Docker Desktop product does that under the hood.